FIR filters with even-symmetric and odd-symmetric coefficients zero placement
I'm taking a course on DSP. Recently there was a statement made about the zeroes of a even-symmetric/odd-symmetric FIR filter being limited to reciprocal conjugates. It was implied that this followed from the definition of the FIR transfer function $$H(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{(N-1)}h[n]z^{-n}$$ (where h[n] is an element in the given even-symmetric/odd-symmetric vector of coefficients). I managed to quite easily find that in the even-symmetric case $$H(z) = z^{-(N-1)}\sum_{n=0}^{(N-1)}h[n]z^{n}$$ and in the odd-symmetric case $$H(z) = -z^{-(N-1)}\sum_{n=0}^{(N-1)}h[n]z^{n}$$ which I believe is on the right track, but I'm failing to make the next connection in determining how this imposes conjugate reciprocal constraints on the zeroes.
Could anyone point me in the right direction?
EDIT (1) :
I have found a resource discussing four different FIR types,
https://eeweb.engineering.nyu.edu/iselesni/EL713/zoom/linphase.pdf
EDIT (2) :
To clarify the question I'm asking, how does one mathematically intuit from, $$H(z)=\pm z^{-(N-1)}H\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)$$ that FIR filters with linear phase have reciprocal conjugate roots.

This question is similar to: What is the reason behind complex conjugate pairs in Linear Phase FIR filter analysis from the Pole Zero plot. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Note that for a FIR filter with real-valued coefficients we have
$$H(z)=H^*(z^*)\tag{1}$$
Consequently, if $z_0$ is a zero of $H(z)$ then $z_0^*$ must also be a zero. This holds for any real-valued FIR filter, regardless of the phase.
For real-valued linear-phase filter we know that
$$H(z)=\pm z^{-M}H\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)\tag{2}$$
must hold. So for any finite zero $z_0$ of $H(z)$, from $(2)$ we can see that $1/z_0$ must also be a zero of $H(z)$.
In sum, if $z_0$ is a zero of a linear-phase filter and if $z_0$ has a non-zero imaginary part, then we know that $z_0^*$, $1/z_0$, and $1/z_0^*$ must also be zeros of $H(z)$. If $z_0$ is real-valued then we only have one other zero at $1/z_0$.

Is (1) a consequence of the conjugate root theorem (in which case I thought this would only hold true for specific values of z), and if not how do you derive that relationship?

@noob1232: Don't think in terms of theorems that you need to remember. In this case it's absolutely straightforward. If you have a polynomial $P(z)$ with real-valued coefficients, conjugating it will only conjugate the variable $z$ (because the real-valued coefficients remain unchanged). That's why we must have $P^(z)=P(z^)$. As simple as that.
